# rest with Spring boot + spring security with custom users table

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I want to configure Spring boot and spring security for some rest services.
I have tables User, priviledge, priviledge_user
I have this Configuration files

WebSecurityConfig

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().
                httpBasic().and().
                csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

and AuthenticationConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }

    @Bean
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsService() {

            @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

                User account = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
                log.info("The user ({}) logged has the password {}", username, account.getPassword());
                org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User userSession =  new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(account.getUsername(), account.getPassword(), true, true, true, true,
                        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER"));
                return userSession;
            }

        };
    }
}
```

debuging the code seems Authentication is working well cause I have the user from database(I am using JNDI datasoure and have this configured in application.properties)
but When I try to get anything on http://localhost:8080/ and set my credentials I cant access and always get the prompt for credentials
Whats I am doing bad?

Comment: Do you have a valid user in database? What does the logging say?

Comment: Yes I have a valid user in the database, I don't have error in the log only have
`2015-11-09 17:07:26,069 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.listener.AuditListener] (default task-2) AuditEvent [timestamp=Mon Nov 09 17:07:26 BOT 2015, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]
`

Answer (score 0):

You are not instantiating the UserDetails object with the correct authorities.

Instead of always passing "USER" to AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList method, you should pass a List with all the roles/privileges in the privilege_user table for the user you are loading. This roles by default are in the form of "ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN"...

So loading the User from the database successfully doesn't mean the authentication process is working well. You still have to tell him how to load the authorities for that User.

Comment: So, I not assigned yet the roles in the database then I think if I set to all users the same role(USER), this should permit the access right?
I need configure which role should permit some method in the controllers?

Comment: I set in my Personcontroller class
@PreAuthorize("USER")
but this still not working

Comment: Try setting "ROLE_USER" instead of "USER" in AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"). I think the role in the database musut have the "ROLE_" prefix, although you can still check for "USER" on your @PreAuthorize("USER"), since Spring security will add the prefix by default. Also, try hitting just localhost:8080 instead of the url for your PersonController method and see what happpens. With your configuration this should ask you for credentials but without  validating any authorities.

Comment: I changed USER to ROLE_USER but this still not working also I noticed this other error<br/>
`[INFO  [org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.listener.AuditListener] (default task-60) AuditEvent [timestamp=Mon Nov 09 20:26:10 EST 2015, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]
[0mtask-23) AuditEvent [timestamp=Mon Nov 09 20:25:42 EST 2015, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are using the DB audit with either of @CreatedBy or @LastModifiedBy annotation and yet you are trying to insert a document before any user is logged in. This use to happen, when you create a new user or create operations in a landing page controller. To overcome this, have a system user in your DB, say, system@yourdomain.com then set principal in the corresponding controller if the input params are right.

While doing so, the DBAuditor will get your system user id for the annotated filed. Make sure, you load newly created user principal after this operation.